# nockBack fails to record any fixtures

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, nock

I cannot get [nockBack](https://github.com/nock/nock#nock-back) to record any fixtures, although it should do that. My test code looks as follows:

```
describe("#searchForProjects", function () {
beforeEach(function () {
  nock.back.setMode("record");
  this.con = getTestConnection(ApiType.Production);
});

it("finds a home project", async function () {
  const { nockDone, context } = await nock.back("search_for_project.json");

  await searchForProjects(this.con, "home:dancermak", {
    idOnly: true,
    exactMatch: true
  }).should.eventually.deep.equal([
    {
      name: "home:dancermak",
      apiUrl: normalizeUrl(ApiType.Production)
    }
  ]);

  nockDone();
});
```

});

Just running this specific test results in a `NetConnectNotAllowedError: Nock: Disallowed net connect for $URL`.

I have tried including a `nock.restore()` before the whole test, which results in the request going through, but nock doesn't bother recording anything.

The underlying code is using the `https` module from nodejs, so that shouldn't be a problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you set the back.fixtures option? Is there an existing recording in the fixtures dir? Does your code make multiple requests to $URL during a single call?

Comment: I do set the `back.fixtures` option. There is no recording in the fixtures directory and none is created without the `nock.restore()` call. With the `nock.restore()` call, the file `search_for_project.json` is created, but it only contains an empty array. The function in question makes only one request to $URL.

Comment: are your tests calling `nock.disableNetConnect()` at all?

Comment: This one definitely is not (and I specifically ran **just** this one). Also, `disableNetConnect()` is called by `nockBack` itself when switching to the mode to `record`.

Comment: Is there nothing in the debug output that is unexpected to you? It's hard to help more without a reproducible example.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get nock to log anything, as it just denies the connection. 
I have pushed the file in question to github: https://github.com/SUSE/open-build-service-api/blob/nock_back_issue/test/integration/search.test.ts

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to crack this and the solution is embarrassingly simple: recording must be activated **before** creating any `http(s).request` calls. In my case it was obscured a bit as I have a class that on construction saves either `http.request` or `https.request` in a member variable. Activating the recorder beforehands solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I had a failing assertion in my test. This meant that `nockDone` was not called and so no nocks were written to disk.